# VB.NET How to end all Subs

Tags: vb.net

I'm having trouble finding a way to end all running Subs. I understand from VBA the keyword "End" is the way to do it however I can't find the equivalent for VB.NET. Can someone help with this? I've tried "Stop" and "Exit Sub" however they only seem to stop the current Sub, not the Sub in which the current one is nested in.

```
If EmptyCell = True Then
   MsgBox("Blank cell(s) detected")
   Stop
End If
```

Thanks.

Comment: *"I understand from VBA the keyword "End" is the way to do it however I can't find the equivalent for VB.NET"*. Um, it's `End` in all flavours of VB. That said, you shouldn't use it in VB.NET. Why exactly do you want to? Why can't you just exit your application properly?

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to terminate the application (a .Net app is not a script) or you want to return from a method call to the method that executed the one you want to exit from or another one, like exiting from nested loops to the current method or to the main procedure, the one that executed the method where the loops are running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Exit Sub instead of stop

If EmptyCell = True Then

MsgBox("Blank cell(s) detected")

Exit Sub

End If

It will come out from sub